# Is it required to use XCode v5 to host an IOS Mobile App in itunesconnect.com?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it required to use XCode v5 to host an IOS Mobile App in itunesconnect.com?

let us know what's the minimum required XCode Version to use?

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you like to use the most recent version? I don't think Apple will keep supporting older versions as they keep changing many stuff each version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. On January, Apple, sent and email to the Developers stating that:

> Starting February 1, **new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK**.

This can be found, too, in the [iOS7](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/) developer's page, were it's added:

> Use Xcode 5 with iOS 7 SDK to compile, **validate**, and **submit** release versions of your iOS 7 apps to iTunes Connect.